# Counting GUAG introns in chromosomes

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, perl, bioinformatics

I have this code that is working fine but it's taking pretty much 100% of my cpu to run and it takes around 25min. I'd really like to optimize it but don't know what parts I could improve.

The main problem I guess is that I'm using coordinates of a file to be compared with a 3,5GB file.
So I tried putting the information of this 3,5GB file in a hash to make it faster but it's not what I thought it would be.
I want to compare exon coordinates to the whole human genome (hg38), see which two letters are before the exon position and which two are in the end, so that would count as an intron. Then, for each intron I want to see if those two letters are compatible with GUAG or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter file path (refGene)\n";
my $ref_gene = <>; 
chomp ($ref_gene);
my $local1 = "./$ref_gene";

print "Enter file path (hg38)\n";
my $filename = <>; 
chomp ($filename);
my $local2 = "./$filename";

open (HG, $local2) or die "error opening $filename\n";

my %chromosome;
my $key;
while (my $line = <HG>) {
    chomp ($line);
    if ($line =~ /^\>/) {
        $key = $line;
        $key =~ s/\>//;          # / stop editor red coloring
        $chromosome{$key} = "";
    }
    else {
        $chromosome{$key} .= uc $line;
    }}

close (HG);

open (REFGENE, $local1) or die "error opening $ref_gene\n";

my $total_introns = 0;
my $GUAG_introns = 0;
while (my $line = <REFGENE>) {
    my @column = split ("\t", $line);
    my $chr = $column[2]; 
    my $sense = $column[3];
    my $number_exons = $column[8];
    my $beginning_of_exon = $column[9];
    my $end_of_exon = $column[10];

    my @beginning_exons = split (",", $beginning_of_exon);
    my @end_exons = split (",", $end_of_exon);
    foreach my $element (@end_exons) { #subtract 1 from end of exon because its 1-based index
        $element -= 1;
    }

    my $introns = ($number_exons - 1); #amount of introns = exons - 1
    $total_introns += $introns;

    my $current_seq = $chromosome{$chr};

    for (my $i=0; $i<@beginning_exons-1; $i++) {
        my $end = substr ($current_seq, $end_exons[$i]+1, 2); #get two letters after end of exon
        my $beginning = substr ($current_seq, $beginning_exons[$i+1]-2, 2); #get two letters before beggining of exon

        if ($sense eq "+") {
            if ( ($end eq "GT") && ($beginning eq "AG") ) {
            $GUAG_introns += 1;
            }}

        elsif ($sense eq "-") {

            if ( ($end eq "CT") && ($beginning eq "AC") ) {
                $GUAG_introns += 1;
            }}}
}

close (REFGENE);


my $GUAG = (($GUAG_introns/$total_introns)*100); #percentage of GUAG introns
print "number of GUAG introns = $GUAG_introns \n total introns = $total_introns \n";
print " $GUAG% of GT-AG introns.\n\n";

exit;
```

input

```
717     NM_000525       chr11   -       17385248        17388659        17386918        17388091        1       17385248,       17388659,     
987     NM_000242       chr10   -       52765379        52771700        52768136        52771635        4      52765379,52769246,52770669,52771448,    52768510,52769315,52770786,52771700,
```

The two letters before the exon position would be AG or the last two letters of an intron

column 9 has the coordinates to the start of an exon and column 10 to the end, I'm trying to get the things in the middle and see if they start with GT and end with AG. Column 3 is the sense of the sequence, so if it's negative (-) instead of looking for GUAG (U cause it's RNA in the end but the reference(hg38) is T) I'll be looking for the reverse complement (AC instead of GT, and CT instead of AG). Column 2 is the chromosome, so for chromosome 6 I'd look the reference in hg38 for chromosome 6 and count the introns. The other file is 15MB

I know it's a lot of code and that nobody will download 3,5GB of human genome to run this but I'd like to know which kind of improvements I can do to optimize the code and not use 100% of cpu.

I put a small part of the [input file](http://pastebin.com/raw/gzy6MgRt) and the [hg38](http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a program that seems to work and produce the same results as your own code. However I have a problem in that the intron doesn't seem to be defined properly

Suppose my sequence is the alphabet and the exons we have are defined by

```perl
@beginning_exons = (5, 17);
@end_exons       = (12, 21);
```

```
                  1                   2 
1 2 3 4|5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2|3 4 5 6|7 8 9 0 1|2 3 4 5 6 
A B C D|E F G H I J K L|M N O P|Q R S T U|V W X Y Z 
        [=============] <-----> [=======]
```

so they are `EFGHIJKL` and `QRSTU`, forming an intron `MNOP`. The calculation in your program, and in my code that produces the same result, gives `$end = 'MN'`, which is fine, but `$beginning = 'PQ'`, which I don't understand. It is the last character of the intron and the first character of the exon

Can this be right? I have put exactly the values above into your code and mine and get the same result

---

#### Update

As usual, the solution was staring me in the face. I am confident that the values you extract to `@beginning_exons` and `@end_exons` are *not* character positions but *offsets*, that may be passed directly to `substr`. It was your comment *"subtract 1 from end of exon because its 1-based index"* that threw me

So it is the *gaps between* the letters that are numbers from zero at the start of the string. Like this

```
                    1                   2 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 A B C D|E F G H I J K L|M N O P|Q R S T U|V W X Y Z 
         [=============] <-----> [=======]
```

Now the "exon" `EFGHIJKL` starts at 4 and ends at 12, and `QRSTU` starts at 16 and ends at 21, making the data look like this

```
@beginning_exons = (4, 16);
@end_exons       = (12, 21);
```

Assuming this makes the arithmetic much easier, because there is no off-by-one error to account for, and the start and end of the intron are 12 and 16—the end of the first exon and the beginning of the next. Furthermore, numbers can be fed directly into `substr` without any offset, except that the last two characters of the intron are clearly at (6-2)

I've modified my code below to take this into account, and it makes it much clearer to read

---

Here's my solution

The main reason yours is so slow is that it's reading the HG38 file line by line, which means it has to upper case each line and append it to the sequence up to 4 million times per sequence

That's very slow because the repeated appending will mean that the string will frequently become too big for the space allocated to it, and it has to be copied to a larger space before it can be expanded. Copying such a huge string thousands of times takes a lot of processor work

I have written it so that a whole chromosome is read at a cctime. Then all that has to be done is to remove the newlines and set it to upper case, just once

I've also printed the each chromosome's name when it is encountered, to give some confirmation that the process is progressing. (You can stop this by removing the `print "    $key\n"` statement.) The time taken to test the introns at the end is minimal

As I said, this code produces the results 492784 /499504 that you expect, but I'm still concerned about the end pair of bases. Please let me know if you have an explanation

```perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my ( $ref_gene_file, $hg38_file ) = qw/ refGene.txt hg38.fa /;

my %chromosome;

{
    print "Processing HG38:\n";

    open my $hg38_fh, '<', $hg38_file or die qq{Error opening "$hg38_file" for input: $!};

    local $/ = '>';

    my $key;

    while ( <$hg38_fh> ) {

        next unless /[^>\s]/;

        s/(.+)// and $key = $1;
        printf "    %s\n", $key;

        $chromosome{$key} = uc tr/A-Za-z//cdr;
    }

    print "\n";
}

my $total_introns = 0;
my $GUAG_introns  = 0;

{
    open my $ref_gene_fh, '<', $ref_gene_file
            or die qq{Error opening "$ref_gene_file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$ref_gene_fh> ) {

        my @column = split;

        my ( $chr, $sense, $n, $exon_starts, $exon_ends ) = @column[ 2, 3, 8, 9, 10 ];
        my @exon_starts = $exon_starts =~ /\d+/g;
        my @exon_ends   = $exon_ends   =~ /\d+/g;

        die "Data discrepancy" unless @exon_starts == $n and @exon_ends == $n;

        my $introns = $n - 1;    #amount of introns = exons - 1
        $total_introns += $introns;

        my $sequence = $chromosome{$chr} or die "No such chromosome";

        for my $i ( 0 .. $introns-1 ) {

            my ($intron_start, $intron_end) = ( $exon_ends[$i], $exon_starts[$i+1] );

            my $intron_prefix = substr( $sequence, $intron_start, 2 );
            my $intron_suffix = substr( $sequence, $intron_end-2, 2 );

            if ( $sense eq '+' ) {
                ++$GUAG_introns if $intron_prefix eq 'GT' and $intron_suffix eq 'AG';
            }
            elsif ( $sense eq '-' ) {
                ++$GUAG_introns if $intron_prefix eq 'CT' and $intron_suffix eq 'AC';
            }
        }
    }
}

printf "Number of GUAG introns = %d\n", $GUAG_introns;
printf "Total introns = %d\n",          $total_introns;
printf "%.1f%% of GT-AG introns.\n\n",  $GUAG_introns / $total_introns * 100;
```

#### output

```
Processing HG38:
    chr1
    chr10
    chr11
    chr11_KI270721v1_random
    chr12
    chr13
    chr14
    ...

Number of GUAG introns = 492784
Total introns = 499504
98.7% of GT-AG introns.

[Finished in 39.1s]
```

Comment: Yes, it should be OP. I'll check that.

Comment: @Tomb: But fixing it inevitably gives different results. (The fix is to set `-1` to `-2` in the assignment to `$intron_suffix`.)

Comment: @Tomb: The fix produces a result of 11 GUAG introns out of 499504 uising the full `refGene.txt` file

Comment: thank you a lot. This is much faster!
I guess the confusion could be because I though about subtracting 1 from every end position to consider it 0-based then that's why the -2.

Comment: @Tomb: I've resolved the issue. The indexes in your `refGene.txt` file *aren't* 1-based, they're zero-based, and reflect the *offset* of the beginning and end of each exon within the sequence. Taking the alphabet as an example again, `ABC` starts at offset zero and ends at offset 3, while we were assuming that is starts at character 1 and ends at character 3. So the exon starting indexes (the ends of the introns) were off by one, resulting in a character pair that straddled the end of the intron. Treating the data as zero-based offsets makes everything work and provides the results you expect.

Comment: @Tomb: By the way, whatever you do you won't get this code to run much faster that the 40 seconds or so that it currently takes. A standard disk drive will read data at arouns 100MB per second, so it will take 35 seconds just to read the 3.5GB HG38 data.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer your question, because I don't actually understand the problem you're trying to solve, and therefore optimise.

However a couple of general points:

- the slowest thing you can do is disk IO. Minimise how much you do, but be wary of the RAM tradeoff.
- Places where algorithms *tend* to slow down is in the loops. Consider how many times you spin the inner loops, and if there's any way of avoiding that.
- Download a profiler, use that to figure out where your code is spending time. `Devel::NYTProf` is one option, but there are others.

Comment: Reading a 3.5GB file should take no more than 35 seconds unless it's on a network drive

Answer (score 4):

A 3.5GB file will take up more memory if stored in a hash, probably more memory than is in your computer (it could be 10 times the file size). If so, you may want to hash the other file if it is (much) smaller and read the FASTA file line by line to build up the sequences.

---

Some other observations on your program.

```
my @beginning_exons = split (",", $beginning_of_exon);
my @end_exons = split (",", $end_of_exon);
foreach my $element (@end_exons) { #subtract 1 from end of exon because its 1-based index
    $element -= 1;
}
```

I wonder why you don't subtract 1 from the elements in `@beginning_exons` too since they are also 1-based (start counting from 1 instead of 0).

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @beginning_exons - 1; $i++)
```

This misses the last element of the array. I think you need this instead. (The web page made '$i' into '$I'. That's not what I entered )

```
for (my $i=0; $i < @beginning_exons; $i++)
```

I'm not sure this indexes into your string correctly

```
    my $beginning = substr ($current_seq, $beginning_exons[$i+1]-2, 2);
```

If you were to subtract 1 from the elements in the `@beginning_exons` array like you did for the `@end_exons` array, then I think the following would be correct.

```
    my $beginning = substr ($current_seq, $beginning_exons[$i]-2, 2);
```

Comment: I have run a test with the OP's own data. The data file is 3.05GB and the resulting hash is 2.99GB, mainly because of the removal of whitespace. The hash has 455 keys, and the values average 7 million characters in length

Comment: @Borodin Yes, my test was flawed by an error in the program. When I reran it, I got results similar to yours. I was accumulating sequences for each key successively instead of resetting the sequence to empty when starting with subsequent keys. And, upon rereading his further requirements, some of the code I thought was in error was actually correct.